# Did Not Receive Confirmation Email to Add Login

Tags: support, login, email

In Stack Overflow, I went to edit profile -> my logins -> add more logins, put in email and password - but did not receive a confirmation email (checked junk email).

How do I update my login info?

Comment: me too , dont know hoe to proceed , contacted tema but no reply so far